# interrupt fadeTo function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Is there a way to interrupt the fadeTo animation on mouseover? For example: In the below code when someone hovers OFF "slider$controls" they fade to .1 opacity at 1750ms, but when you hover ON them they fade to 1 opacity at 500ms. If someone were to hover OFF of them and before the 1750ms was up they hovered back on them, slider$controls would not fade back to 1 opacity until the 1750ms was up which makes it appear unresponsive.

```
$(function () {
    var fadeDelay = 4000,
        // hide after 3 second delay
        timer, hideControls = function (slider) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            setTimeout(function () {
                slider.$controls.hover(function () {
                $(this).fadeTo(500, 1.0);
                }, function () {
                $(this).fadeTo(1750, 0.1);
                });
            }, fadeDelay);
        };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.stop()` to clear animations from the queue/stop the current animation.

Best use it like this:

```
$(function () {
    var fadeDelay = 4000,
        // hide after 3 second delay
        timer, hideControls = function (slider) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            setTimeout(function () {
                slider.$controls.hover(function () {
                $(this).stop(true,false).fadeTo(500, 1.0);
                }, function () {
                $(this).stop(true,false).fadeTo(1750, 0.1);
                });
            }, fadeDelay);
        };
});
```

This will clear the queue, so all animations are stopped and then start the animation from where the element has been stopped.

Comment: I don't think `.stop(true,true)` is really a nice solution here as the animation would jump. with `.stop(true,false)` it continues from where it has been interrupted :)

Comment: this works perfectly :) will mark this as correct answer when time limit permits me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use jQuery's [`.stop`](http://%20api.jquery.com/stop) function:

```
$(function () {
    var fadeDelay = 4000,
        // hide after 3 second delay
        timer, hideControls = function (slider) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            setTimeout(function () {
                slider.$controls.hover(function () {
                $(this).stop(1,1).fadeTo(500, 1.0);
                }, function () {
                $(this).stop(1,1).fadeTo(1750, 0.1);
                });
            }, fadeDelay);
        };
});
```

What this does is stops the current animations, and jumps to the final result before starting the next animation.

Answer (score 0):

If you call the [stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method on the element it will stop all animations.

Answer (score 0):

```
.hover( function() {
    $( this ).stop().fadeTo( 500, 1.0 );
}, function() {
    $( this ).stop().fadeTo( 1750, 0.1 );
});
```